# How to launch an IE session using Selenium-Webdriver with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find this answer through search but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.  I Googled this for a bit and am thinking I may need "InternetExplorerDriver", but my understanding is that this is for the RC server, and I am not using this.  Is there a way to run IE natively through Selenium-Webdriver for Ruby without a lot extra?  Or am I better off trying Powershell or something for IE?

EDIT:  Also, it sounds like 32-bit is the preferred IE version, so I guess my question is specifically about launching 32-bit IE.  Running Windows 7 if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need the InternetExplorerDriver. There is a section in the [Watirbook](https://leanpub.com/watirbook/read#leanpub-auto-windows-81) that lays out the instructions step-by-step.

Basically it is:

1. Install the Selenium-WebDriver gem
2. Download and unzip the InternetExplorerDriver
3. Put the InternetExplorerDriver somewhere in your path

Then you just a script to open IE:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :internet_explorer
```